# How to populate a form with radio group

Tags: jquery

I have a form with lot of radio groups. I want to populate this form using jquery. My question is posted in js fiddle

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <input type="radio" name="a[1]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="a[1]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="a[1]"/>
    <br>
     <input type="radio" name="b[1]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="b[1]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="b[1]"/>
    <br>
     <input type="radio" name="b[2]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="b[2]"/>
    <input type="radio" name="b[2]"/>
</form>
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujithwayanad/eQeZg/)

help me

Comment: add the question in question body

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add jquery in your fiddle and made some correction on it..

```
function populate(frm, data) {
 $.each(data, function(key, value){
   $('[name="'+key+'"]', frm).val(value); //here added ""
   $('[name="'+key+'"]', frm).attr("checked", value);
 });
}
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/eQeZg/1/)

Comment: thank you for the help but now I have another problem can you please see this too... http://jsfiddle.net/sujithwayanad/eQeZg/4/
i need to select the radio once its value is equal to the json

Comment: do you understand what I mean.. ??

Comment: no... `once its value is equal to json`... but with your codes and fiddle... value remains the same for all the three radio button with name `a[1]`.. and similar fot other radios

Comment: sorry there was some server problem it has not saved.
http://jsfiddle.net/sujithwayanad/eQeZg/5/
here is the new one

Answer (score 0):

Error was with your selector `$('[name="'+key+'"]', frm)`.. Since `key` has `[`,`]` symbols (`a[1]`,`a[2]` etc..), you should make it `$('[name="'+key+'"]', frm)`..

Also you forgot to add jQuery library to your fiddle..

Try:

```
function populate(frm, data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('[name="'+key+'"]', frm).val(value);
     $('[name="'+key+'"]', frm).attr("checked", value);
  });
}
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/EQmeJ/)**

Comment: hi I got your answer thankyou for that but now I have another problem 
http://jsfiddle.net/sujithwayanad/eQeZg/5/ 
please check this I need to select only when the value is matched
thank you...